# A network file on windows is different for different users

Tags: windows, networking

I replaced an executable on the network with a new version. Because other people had the executable opened, I could not overwrite or delete the file. I moved the old file to another location, which did allow me to place the new executable at the old location of the old file.

A few weeks later, I discovered that other users would still run the old executable, while I myself was running the new executable. Both me and the other users would see the modified date of the new file. Is Windows somehow buffering the file? Is this to prevent load on the network? What could I do to force the users to use the latest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only buffer is the RAM of the client computers: the previous instance may still be running if it has never been closed.

However, if they are using shortcuts, you should know that Windows Explorer can find the original (old) file and update the shortcut accordingly:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121008-00/?p=6383

> What could I do to force the users to use the latest file?

You should delete the old file.

However, if you are updating this file regularly, you should conisder using a "launcher" , for example: a simple powershell or batch file that will only be used to start the main executable. Then, instruct your users to start the program using this launcher.

This will allow you to edit the launcher file to reference the correct version when needed, something like that:

```
\\share\soft
        │ launcher.bat -> start ...\1.5\tool.exe
        │
        ├───v1.0
        │       tool.exe
        │
        ├───v1.1
        │       tool.exe
        │
        └───v1.5
                tool.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Offline file syncronisation could cause you such problem if by error you enabled it on the folder, as it’s not a good practice to enable such feature on a shared folder.

Make sure the sync center does not sync that folder. As if a sunc error happen, the computer would use the local cached file.